# Drive API - encode pdf string file to base64

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm using the Drive API, particularly the Export functionality https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export to transform a Google Doc to pdf and download it.

```
                $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + id + '/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf',
            {
                headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.token }
            }).then(function (res) {

                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                    fileReader.onloadend = function () {
                        console.log(fileReader.result);
                    };

                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            });
```

I'm using that piece of code (AngularJS), on the console I can see something converted, but when I try to render it, I have an error. The render functionality is working fine because I'm rendering other base64 pdf (not downloaded from Google API) and it works.

The thing is, in the response from Google I have a string like:

> PDF-1.5↵%    ↵2 0 obj↵<< /Linearized 1 /L 22642
>   /…tream↵endob......................."

How can I do to convert that result into a base64 encoded pdf string? No matter if the conversion is on the client side, or even in the server side with NodeJS.

Thanks!